# Remove horizontal scroll from width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My goal with this code is to position an image and text above a background to create a sort of overlay, I have already positioned the image well across all sizes, but my problem is the width creates a long horizontal scrollbar. Looking for a way to keep my css while removing the scroll bar.

**FULL SCREEN VIEW**

[image: 1]

**MOBILE VIEW**

As you can see the width (1000px) is highlighted in blue.

[image: 2]

**HTML**

```
 <div class="banner-partner-padding position-relative" style="background-image: url('img/bg-banners/banner-partner.jpg'); background-size: cover;">
     <div class="header-p">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-6 div-partner text-center">
           <div class="div-partner-content">
             <img src="../img/uploads/<?php echo($rowMerchant['logosrc']); ?>" class="partner-image">
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-6 my-auto pl-4 d-none d-sm-block">
           <?php  echo '<h3 class="bold-font color-white t-shadow-black d-none d-sm-block">'.$rowMerchant['businessname'].'</h3>'; ?>
         </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.banner-partner-padding {
  padding-top: 250px;
}

.header-p {
  width: 1000px !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 210px;
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .header-p {
    width: 1000px !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    left: 50px;
  }
}


@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .header-p {
    width: 1000px !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 140px;
    left: 30px;
  }
}

.div-partner {
    max-width: 13%;
    min-width: 13%;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: flex;
    align-content: center!important;
    align-items: center!important;
}

.div-partner-content {
    display:block;
    margin: auto auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.partner-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display:block;
    margin: auto auto;
}
```

Solutions I tried but did not work:

- adding overflow hidden: the image gets cut and the scroll bar stays

  ```
   .header-p {
     width: 1000px !important;
     position: absolute;
     top: 140px;
     left: 210px;
     overflow-x: hidden;
   }
  ```

[image: 3]

- adding z-index: no change

  ```
   .header-p {
     width: 1000px !important;
     position: absolute;
     top: 140px;
     left: 210px;
     z-index: 1;
   }
  ```

Comment: you're using `!important;` in your CSS, first you should remove it to see how it works. @media screen and (max-width: 576px) { width: 100%; }

Answer (score 0):

Use `max-width: 100%`

Example:

```
.header-p{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Also you should remove `position, width & top` attributes from `@media` because you already declared same value above

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to replicate your issue and modify a bit, you can have a look here:

- Simply move all the content block outside, put them in separate block. Use negative margin top (`margin-top: -40px;`) to move this block up a bit, avoid using `absolute` position in this case.
- Set a height to the background div behind.

As you see, I've removed all `!important` flag in your CSS. In `header-p`, add `.container` class to use default Bootstrap container properties. By default it maximizes the width by 1440px. You can override this number simply by:

This part I don't include in the CSS, just for your reference in case you want to change width value.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
.container.header-p {
   max-width: 1000px;
}
}
```

```css
.banner-partner-padding {
  height: 300px;
}

.container-header {
  margin-top: -40px;
  background: salmon;
}

.div-partner {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 13%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: flex;
}

.div-partner-content {
  display: block;
  margin: auto auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.partner-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: auto auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="banner-partner-padding" style="background-image: url('https://placeimg.com/1000/300/nature'); background-size: cover;">
</div>
<div class="container container-header header-p">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col div-partner text-center">
      <div class="div-partner-content">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/128/128/people" class="partner-image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col my-auto pl-4 d-none d-sm-block">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio reiciendis reprehenderit veritatis eos saepe deleniti asperiores, impedit ad repellendus id eligendi adipisci animi blanditiis perspiciatis laboriosam esse delectus hic, labore commodi optio dolore ipsam. Labore, nesciunt! Corrupti asperiores sit temporibus cupiditate, sunt voluptatibus iure veniam repellat laudantium, aperiam soluta repudiandae.
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat animi nemo laborum facilis doloribus culpa sed numquam illum voluptates esse eaque quos quidem illo facere suscipit, hic, dignissimos totam unde soluta eius est voluptatem magni assumenda neque! Beatae quo perferendis cupiditate soluta, officia esse quam tempore ratione et doloremque aspernatur.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo link: https://codepen.io/DieByMacro/pen/YzzBdZR

Let me know if this is your desired behavior for the content block.